# Elegant way to take and process the first element from a stream before processing the remaining elements

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a Stream that contains rows of a table. The first row contains the header row and should be processed differently. The remaining rows should then be processed in a standard way.

I don't want to skip the header row, because I need the information of that row. The naïve solution would be something like this:

```
Stream<Row> rows = ...;
Row headRow = rows.<what comes here?>;
rows.forEach( this::processRow );
```

But that will obviously not be possible. Nearest thing I can come up with is:

```
Stream<Rows> rows = ...;
AtomicReference<Row> headRow = new AtomicReference<>();
rows.takeWhile(r -> { 
    if (headRow().get()==null) { 
        headRow.set(r); 
        return true;
    }
    return false; 
})
.forEach( this::processRow );
```

This should work but IMHO is somewhat awkward.

Does anyone have a better Idea how to solve this? (It should work on Java 17 without additional libraries like guava.)

Note: Using collect() to create a list first, processing the header row and then converting back to stream and skipping the first element works, but I don't consider it a good solution as it requires much more memory (because all elements have to be held in memory at the same time).

Comment: Maybe streams are not the correct solution in the first place.

Comment: Are you reading a CSV? You should parse the header first, *then* produce a stream with the records. Or don't use a stream at all.

Comment: The Stream API doesn't have any non-terminal method to do what you want. Why do you need to get the first element from the stream? It is possible to fetch the first element before creating the stream?

Comment: Of course, the reason you're not getting elegance is that you're working against the stateless nature of Java streams.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca the input I get from the library is a stream.

Comment: @Olivierwhat it might be a CVS, it might be an excel file or whatever. That's why the header is also returned as a row from the library.

Comment: @MaksimEliseev the first row defines how the cells in the remaining rows are laid out, i. e. the order of columns. I quite like the spliterator solution given in the answer by Lesiak. It's nice enough, and doesn't need to read everything into a collection first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `spliterator`?

```java
Stream<Integer> rows = Stream.of(1, 2, 3);
var spliterator = rows.spliterator();
spliterator.tryAdvance(x -> System.out.println("Header " + x));
spliterator.forEachRemaining(x -> System.out.println("Data " + x));
```

Alternatively, I would consider the following helper function: [`Stream<T> stream(Iterator<T> iterator)`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/41203f03e9b7ddfd776f88660cc467e59bbb180b/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Streams.java#L87C46-L87C85) from Guava. It only depends on JDK classes.

```java
/**
 * Returns a sequential {@link Stream} of the remaining contents of {@code iterator}. Do not use
 * {@code iterator} directly after passing it to this method.
 */
public static <T extends @Nullable Object> Stream<T> stream(Iterator<T> iterator) {
  return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, 0), false);
}
```

Then:

```java
Stream<Integer> rows = Stream.of(1, 2, 3);
var it = rows.iterator();
var headOpt = it.hasNext() ? Optional.of(it.next()) : Optional.empty();
var tail = stream(it);
System.out.println(headOpt);
tail.forEach(System.out::println);
```